# Ubuntu Desktop Module

Tags: 14.04, server

I'm new with **VPS** I have now a **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server**, I connected to the server with Remote Desktop from Windows, but now I just see the terminal. Is there a way to see a desktop (see below image) instead of just a terminal.

[image]

Comment: let's see the easiest way.. do a `ssh -X user@server` properly changing user and server. then after you have typed the password, `gnome-session`

Comment: Why do you actually want a remote desktop on a remote Server install? It's possible but it's not what any of this is designed for.

Comment: Download PuTTy and learn SSH.

Comment: I am not sure if this relates to your question, but Ubuntu Server by default does not come with a GUI. You will need to install one if you wish to interact with the server in this way. http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available has a bunch you can choose from. I don't know if this question is related to not having a GUI, or if the server is virtual inside another server(from VPS). Or how this is set up exactly, in order to address your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in order to access a desktop environment on ubuntu server, you need to have about 1G of ram and you need to install the "ubuntu-desktop" which is not included with the server by default. Do this by typing the following commands in that terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

---

I'm not exactly sure how to access the desktop once it's installed but you need the desktop before you do anything.

If you don't have much ram, you can install something like Lubuntu or Xubuntu like this instead:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

[image]

For Xubuntu,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

[image]

image credits

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/12/xubuntu-1310-same-again-please-bartender.html

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Lubuntu-14-04-LTS-Final-Beta-Is-Out-Can-Run-on-Any-PC-PowerPC-and-Mac-434620.shtml